# How to control power to a nichrome wire coil heating element with 12V DC and 5A Max current

Tags: control, wire, heat, coil, efficiency

What is the best way to manually control the power to a nichrome wire coil heating element with 12V DC and 5A Max current. 
I am looking for a simple and efficient way to control it with a knob for user. Rheostats would be way too inefficient as it will need to dissipate 60W of heat!
Here is the link to the NiChrome coil i'm looking to use:
http://www.omega.com/pptst/NIC60_NIC80.html

Comment: Actually a rheostat would only dissipate 30W worst-case.

Comment: However some form of PWM controller would be more efficient. A 5A 12V DC motor speed controller should be fine.